# ruby sort by date starting on todays date

Tags: ruby, sorting, ruby-on-rails-5

I am trying to sort an array by date starting with todays date. I am using

```
  @bookings.order(start_time: :asc ).each do
```

to sort my list but as you would expect, it is starting at the beginning. How would I return a list that would start with todays date?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
@bookings.where("start_time >= '#{Date.today}'")
         .order(start_time: :asc)
         .each { ... }
```